# How to get parameter with routing rules in CodeIgniter

Tags: php

My base_url is "http://localhost/App-Feeder/"

Default controller is "Detail"

How do i code my routes and controller to get my URL as "http://localhost/App-Feeder/table/place"

Where "place" is a get parameter and should load to another page.
i tried like this :

**my route.php**

```
$route['table/(:any)'] = "detail/lala/(:any)";
```

Controller: **detail.php**

```
class Detail extends CI_Controller {

    public function lala($place)
    {
        echo "choose=".$place;
    }
}
```

but it will display :

```
choose=(:any)
```

it should be display :

```
choose=place
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
 $route['table/(:any)'] = "detail/lala/(:any)";
```

with

```
 $route['table/(:any)'] = "detail/lala/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

for better learning about codeignitor follow this link [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)  and try this for your problem

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";
```